# Append "..." at the end of fourth line

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am displaying text using UILabel. I want to display only 4 lines of text, if there is more text i have to append "..." at the end of fourth line. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
label.numberOfLines = 4;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

or in case you support iOS <= 5.

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i cannot upvote since i dont have enough reputation but surely i will once i get.

Answer (score 1):

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
lbl.numberOfLines = 4;
```

For iOS >= 6,

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
lbl.numberOfLines = 4;
```

Comment: so where is it different to Gabriele's earlier answer?

Comment: No big deal here. Two similar answers on a trivial question is a fairly common case. A part from that, asking the OP to accept mine is kind, but funny. You could just delete your own (and optionally upvote mine) if you feel like it doesn't add any value.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: yes, no big deal — if it wouldn't had been you, who guided Bhargavi to the right answer, as his initial was just wrong.

Comment: @vikingosegundo. Yep, still two right identical answers are better than one right and one wrong. Moreover my answer is already getting its fair share of upvotes, so we can move on happily ever after. :P

Comment: thanks a lot, i cannot upvote since i dont have enough reputation but surely i will once i get.